# Overall width is wider than content (chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome, width, html

theres a problem within my page in which the overall width is wider than the content making the horizontal scrollbar appear http://mayra.adparkour.org, this issue happens to appear in chrome only. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: FYI: See http://www.paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/ to learn more about (Chrome) developer tools, which is what most people would use to find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your `.screen-reader-text` link. You've given it `position: absolute;`, but you still need to do something like `left: -9999em` on it.

Answer (score 0):

It is being caused by this tag:

```
<a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do with that tag, but it is positioned outside of the containing div.

A simple solution is to add `overflow: hidden` to the parent `nav` tag.